# Error Generating Coupon Codes Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have an issue generating coupon codes. When I go to the sales rule and click to generate, it spins for a second and does not show anything on the frontend. It throws a 500 error. I found the error log and this is the error that is happening:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\ConfigInterface in /var/www/vhosts/releases/20200317173828/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/releases/20200317173828/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/releases/20200317173828/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/releases/20200317173828/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/releases/20200317173828/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->cr in /var/www/vhosts/releases/20200317173828/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

This is on an upgraded magento 2.3.4 instance. Everything else is working fine except for this. Rebuilding has not helped, clearing cache, generated folder, etc.

UPDATE: I resolved this error as I did not have the MessageQueue module active. However now getting another error once I enabled it:

```
{"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\Framework\\MessageQueue\\PublisherPool","1":"
#1 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n
#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-sales-rule\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Promo\/Quote\/Generate.php:58]\n
#3 Magento\\SalesRule\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Promo\\Quote\\Generate->__construct() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/SalesRule\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Promo\/Quote\/Generate\/Interceptor.php:14]\n
#4 Magento\\SalesRule\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Promo\\Quote\\Generate\\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n
#5 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:108]\n
#6 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]\n
#7 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/ActionFactory.php:44]\n
#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\ActionFactory->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Router\/Base.php:306]\n
#9 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->matchAction() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Router\/Base.php:167]\n
#10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->match() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:95]\n
#11 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n
#12 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n
#13 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n
#14 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n
#15 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:116]\n
#16 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n
#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n
#18 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n
#19 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:26]\n
#20 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:40]\n","url":"\/eb-admin\/sales_rule\/promo_quote\/generate\/?isAjax=true","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"f76eecbde8d0438dd1c2f09b23b565527e2c804d2d488ed0367f4b2ab44a5925"}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Please provide more details. Don't get enough information from this post

Comment: Since it's a core problem, sound like a compile/permission/generation problem. Or your installation maybe are corrupted. Can you re-install removing the vendor content and ask for new compose install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that both the Magento_MysqlMq Magento_AsynchronousOperations modules are also required. This is not mentioned in either the documentation or the modules. Once enabled, errors went away.